# Joining one record to resultset in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to join the most recent OLD_VAL from my Audit_table which records changes to columns in my main table called Insurance_State.

The problem with my current query is that it is duplicating returned rows in my result set show every single **OLD_VAL** a record in Insurance_State has been

```
        SELECT ins.last_upd, cc.id, cc.claim_date, pol.policy_id, ins.state, adt.old_val, ins.review_date, ins.latest_reason, bll.ou_num
    FROM CUSTOMER_CLAIM cc
    JOIN CUSTOMER_CAR car
    ON cc.id = car.ccid
    JOIN POLICY pol
    ON car.integ_id = pol.integ_id
    JOIN INSURANCE_STATE ins
    ON pol.policy_id = ins.policy_id
    JOIN BILLING_ACCT bll
    ON pol.bill_accnt_id = bll.row_id
    --only want to the most recent record from below table
    JOIN AUDIT_TABLE adt
ON pol.policy_id = hst.policy_id
```

The output this gives in very simplistic terms is

```
D --> A
D --> B
D --> C
```

When in reality I only want the most recent old_val so the output would be

```
D --> C
```

How can I adjust my query so it does that.

I tried doing a inner select statement inside the join but It does not like my syntax

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have a little mistake:

```
JOIN AUDIT_TABLE adt ON pol.policy_id = hst.policy_id
```

May be so:

```
JOIN AUDIT_TABLE adt ON pol.policy_id = adt.policy_id
```

And answer to your question:

```
join (
    select policy_id, old_val from (  
          select at.policy_id, at.old_val, 
                 rank() over (partition by at.policy_id order by at.old_val desc) as rnk 
          from AUDIT_TABLE at
        ) where rnk = 1
    ) adt on pol.policy_id = adt.policy_id
```

This should work if the statuses are such names (A, B, C, D, etc.). If it is not, in expression `order by at.old_val desc` you should use a different field, like a id, or addition time.

Comment: What if I was to use a column in Audit_table called "Change_Date"

Comment: Apologies for obfuscating my query

Comment: Did I understand correctly that the record is added to the table when status changes? And field "Change_Date" - addition time of such record? If so - this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Yea can I use ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE DESC to get the most recent change.